# How to Select Element Based on Parameters Passed in Button Onclick Method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to select the button that has the timestamp i am targeting. Here is the HTML:

```
<a class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated mdc-ripple-upgraded" href="#" onclick="selectTime(7160, null, &quot;2021-08-23T08:15:00-04:00&quot;, '8b96beed5b0b8f7b34e51853f14ef6eb'); return false;" style="--mdc-ripple-fg-size:55px; --mdc-ripple-fg-scale:1.97805; --mdc-ripple-fg-translate-start:17px, -19.5px; --mdc-ripple-fg-translate-end:18.5px, -9.5px;">
                    <div class="mdc-button__ripple"></div>
                    <span class="mdc-button__label">8:15 AM</span>
                </a>
```

I do not know how to target the timestamp parameter it is calling in onclick that can be used to select the button. I have tried to find element by targeting the label's text, but I cannot click on the label, with it giving me this error :

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="mdc-button__label">...</span> is not clickable at point (132, 380). Other element would receive the click: <div class="mdc-button__ripple"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below `css_selector` :

```
a[class$='mdc-ripple-upgraded'] span[class='mdc-button__label']
```

use it like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='mdc-ripple-upgraded'] span[class='mdc-button__label']")))).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: where do I specify the text of the label?

Comment: You don't need to, Do you just wanna click on the button ? Also text can change right in future?

Comment: sorry to clarify it's a list of buttons, each with a unique text label; how can I select the outter button based on the nested span element's text?

Comment: okay I thought time text would change,  anyway if it's unique try using this xpath `//span[text()='8:15 AM']/..` use it like `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='8:15 AM']/..")))).click().perform()`

Comment: oh sorry it does change, the times change everyday, anyway I can do partial text in that method?

Comment: I think the first answer in my solution should work if time changes dynamically, try that out

Comment: got a few bugs in them unable to select and wait is undefined

Comment: the one in the comments worked by I want to select the hour specifically because the minutes vary day by day

Comment: for those issues, you should import, I have given you all the imports

Comment: I want to select the hour specifically because the minutes vary day by day - in this case try this `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='8']/..")))).click().perform()` and let me know if you run into any issues.